# How to create an issue on JIRA using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

I google it for getting a proper solution to create issue on jira using node.js. But didn't get any solution yet. Anybody can suggest me a proper way or give a sample code for doing this.

Comment: Did you find a module you could use? Have you tried something? Show what your tried to do so we can start somewhere. We are not here to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a node package for this already. The documentation of for the NPM module has a code sample that should make this easy to do.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira